Trying to run django for the first time
I can't access files in my app hello in my template, rendering them does not work.
Here is my github repo to understand the issue https://github.com/Firiceee/Bug_django .
I tryed to understand where does the problem come from as u can see with the exept, and effectively it triggers the except, furthermore, the last render, simpler does already not work, it's like , I can't access my directory "templates"...

A common error is forgetting to add an app to settings.INSTALLED_APPS it looks like you didn't do that for the hello app.

Please make sure to include a [mre] in the text of your question itself. A GitHub link alone is generally not sufficient.

I checked your repository, here some problems:
1:

Add the hello app to the INSTALL_APPS.

2:

When you render your test.html template, the syntax is wrong, you have to write the app name and then the template name, write like this:
return render(request,"hello/test.html")



The issue was that I had forgotten to link my app hello in my settings, a big thanks !
